# Why is my nav bar not all the way at the top and 100% width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a nav bar at the top of my webpage: http://www.giltmantis.com and there's like 5px or so of white around it.  Why is it not the full width and all the way at the top?

here's the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.giltmantis.com/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav"><img src="giltmantis5.png"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css:

```
#nav { float: left; clear: both; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #000; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `body` tag has an 8px margin.

set `body { margin: 0}` in your css.

Answer (score 2):

Your body has a margin of 8px, set it either to 0 or remove it from your body.

Webpage without margin:
[image: HERE]